# Conflict Refiner Preferences Cplex

Tags: java, preferences, linear-programming, cplex

As far as I understood, in ConflictRefiner of CPLEX, the preference array should guide the method to find the conflict Set that is more desirable. But in the code below, no matter how do I modify the pref array, the same constraints (C1, C3) are returned every time as conflict set, although the other conflict set (C2, C3) is more desirable for me. Would you please help me how I should set the preferences to get (C2) and (C3) as a conflict set?

```
        IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
        IloNumVar x = cplex.numVar(0, Double.MAX_VALUE, "x");
        IloNumVar y = cplex.numVar(0, Double.MAX_VALUE, "y");

        IloLinearNumExpr objective = cplex.linearNumExpr();

        objective.addTerm(16 , x);
        objective.addTerm(9, y);

        // Define objective function
        cplex.addMinimize(objective);

        IloRange[] constrtaints = new IloRange[3];
        constrtaints[0] = cplex.addGe(cplex.sum(x,y), 5, "C1");
        constrtaints[1] = cplex.addGe(cplex.sum(x,y), 2, "C2");
        constrtaints[2] = cplex.addLe(cplex.sum(x,y), 1, "C3");

        System.out.println(cplex.toString());

        if (!cplex.solve()) {
            double[] pref = new double[3];
            pref[0] = 2;
            pref[1] = 10;
            pref[2] = 9;

            if (cplex.refineConflict(constrtaints , pref)) {
                IloCplex.ConflictStatus[] conflict = cplex.getConflict(constrtaints);
                for (int c2 = 0; c2 < constrtaints.length; c2++)
                    if (conflict[c2] == IloCplex.ConflictStatus.Member)
                        System.out.println(constrtaints[c2]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Explain exactly what you tried and provide some more context.

Comment: I changed pref[0], pref[1] and pref[2] to different values with different orders but {C1,  C3} is returned as conflict set all the time. While there are more than one conflict set and the one that I am more interested in is {C2, C3}

Comment: This question was cross-posted [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/458138/setting-preferences-of-conflictrefiner-in-cplex.html?childToView=458152#answer-458152).

Comment: I could not find any answers there either. I posted it there too!